# Open link only on mobile devices in a new tab

Tags: php, html

*Im working on a web project and got into trouble:*

**On PC** the link directs to a iframe lightbox and it works. Thats cool.

**On mobile devices** nothing happens when clicking on the link (no iframe box opens..)

So I thought the solution could be: On mobile devcices it just opens a new tab instead of the iframe lightbox

Is that possible? How´s the code to open a link in a new tab just on mobile devices?

Comment: Simple solution would be to have two links, and only show one via css restricted on the viewport size. `@media (max-width: yourMobileWidth) { ... }`

Comment: show us some code how you're writing links and iframes

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your approach, Yes its possible in JavaScript in two steps.

1) Identify whether it's a mobile device.

2) Open Links accordingly.

```
object.onclick = function(){
    if (/Android|Windows|iPhonewebOS|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        Console.log("Mobile Device Found, Open Links in a new Tab");
        function openInNewTab(url) {
            var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
            win.focus();
        }
    }
    else{
        Console.log("Mobile Device Not Found, Open Links in lightBox");
        window.open(url,"_self");
    }
};
```